# Darboux property applied for function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function for $x\in[0,1]$ and it has this property that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+1/3)+f(x+2/3)}{x} = 1
$$
How to prove that there exists $t\in[0,1]$ such as $f(t)=0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Existence of solutions of the equation with a limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383883/existence-of-solutions-of-the-equation-with-a-limit) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bf(x%2B1%2F3)%2Bf(x%2B2%2F3)%7D%7Bx%7D%20%24&p=1)

Comment: You just have to find that $f(0)*f(1) \le 1$.